# Do not know how to retrieve information with RightJoin on CakePHP 3.2

Tags: php, cakephp, right-join, cakephp-3.2

- CakePHP Version: 3.2
- Platform and Target: Wamp, MySQq, Google Chrome

#### What I did

Right Join between two tables in one controller. I'm trying to retrieve the information and I can't

```
$query = $this->Schedules->find('all')
  ->rightJoin(['Sessions'=> 'sessions'], ['Sessions.id is not null'])
  ->select(['Sessions.specialist_id'])
  ->where(['Sessions.id ='=>$session])

foreach ($query as $sp) {
  if(!empty($sp)){
    $specialist=$sp->Sessions->specialist_id;
```

#### Expected Behavior

Get the specialist id

#### Actual Behavior

I can't get the specialist id

#### More info

**1** I already tried with `$specialist=$sp->specialist_id;` and nothing happen
**2** With `debug ($sp);die();` this is what I got

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Schedule) {

'Sessions' => [
    'specialist_id' => 'a7f6d5b2-b0f3-4a55-b6ce-41d393e80d12'
],
'[new]' => false,
'[accessible]' => [
    '*' => true
],
'[dirty]' => [],
'[original]' => [],
'[virtual]' => [],
'[errors]' => [],
'[invalid]' => [],
'[repository]' => 'Schedules'
```

}

Comment: "_I want X, but I don't get X_" is pretty much like "_It doesn't work_", which isn't really a proper problem description. Please be more specific as to what _exactly_ happens! Like, does the query retrieve the data that you want? Does the code actually make it to/past the `if`? If so, what exactly is `$specialist`? Also helpful would be to know what your datastructure (the involved schemas and the records) and the issued queries look like (and whether they look like what you'd expect).

Comment: Start with `debug($sp); die;` Do you really want a right join (find all sessions matching conditions, whether they have a schedule or not)?

Comment: What I got with  `debug($sp); die;` is now under the code @AD7six

Comment: The specialist has sessions and the session, one schedule. What I'm trying to do is to validate that if I try to insert one schedule (with a start and an end datetime) and it collide with another schedule (of the same specialist), I must see the information according to the schedule that is already saved. First I need the specialist, so I made that query and yes, it retrieves what I want and past the if statement. If I print $sp, I saw on the screen {"Sessions":{"specialist_id": ->the id that I need<-}} . The problem is that I don't know how to retrieve just the id from $sp. @ndm

Comment: I totally overlooked that `specialist_id` belongs to `Sessions`, and not to `Schedules` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`specialist_id` belongs to `Sessions`, so you need to access it via that key, ie

```
$sp->Sessions['specialist_id']
```

or

```
$sp['Sessions']['specialist_id']
```

or even

```
$sp->get('Sessions')['specialist_id']
```

... oooooor, once [**that feature**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/7847) makes it into the core

```
$sp->get('Sessions.specialist_id')
```

That's rather basic stuff, but maybe the docs could benefit from an example on how to access nested data, including such that is a mix of objects and arrays.

**[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Entities > Accessing Entity Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#accessing-entity-data)**

On a side note, AFAICT `$sp` should never be empty, either there is a result, or there isn't.